# server applicaton always crashes when a destructor function is executed

Tags: c++, valgrind

The server application always crashes at the same line in code. I used gdb and valgrind to find the problem, but it seems the crash point is in a compiler created destructor, and this is what valgrind says:

```
==27785== Invalid read of size 8
==27785==    at 0x5CDCE25: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==27785==    by 0x5812F4: Pet::BookConfiguration::~BookConfiguration() (BookConfiguration.h:8)
==27785==    by 0x5EDEC4: void std::_Destroy<Pet::BookConfiguration>(Pet::BookConfiguration*) (stl_construct.h:107)
==27785==    by 0x5EDEE2: void std::__destroy_aux<Pet::BookConfiguration*>(Pet::BookConfiguration*, Pet::BookConfiguration*, __false_type) (stl_construct.h:12
2)
==27785==    by 0x5EDF17: void std::_Destroy<Pet::BookConfiguration*>(Pet::BookConfiguration*, Pet::BookConfiguration*) (stl_construct.h:155)
==27785==    by 0x5EDF3A: void std::_Destroy<Pet::BookConfiguration*, Pet::BookConfiguration>(Pet::BookConfiguration*, Pet::BookConfiguration*, std::allocator
<Pet::BookConfiguration>) (stl_construct.h:182)
==27785==    by 0x5F5C09: std::vector<Pet::BookConfiguration, std::allocator<Pet::BookConfiguration> >::~vector() (stl_vector.h:272)
==27785==    by 0x5F6A22: Pet::ShopModel::~ShopModel() (ShopModel.h:15)
==27785==    by 0x5C59E3: Pet::PetProcessor::climbFight(Pet::SourceList&, Pet::TBuffer&) (PetProcessor.cpp:1796)
==27785==    by 0x589263: Pet::Processor::execute(Pet::SourceList&, unsigned short, Pet::TBuffer&) (Processor.cpp:22)
==27785==    by 0x578627: Pet::JobThread<Pet::PetProcessor>::run() (JobThread.h:66)
==27785==    by 0x4F81AB2: Poco::PooledThread::run() (in /data/home/app100619699/pet_srv/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.11)
==27785==  Address 0x900df30 is 7 bytes after a block of size 57 free'd
==27785==    at 0x4A201B6: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:457)
==27785==    by 0x5CDCE59: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==27785==    by 0x5CFFE6: Pet::PetProcessor::getUserBag(Pet::SourceList&, Pet::TBuffer&) (PetProcessor.cpp:446)
==27785==    by 0x589263: Pet::Processor::execute(Pet::SourceList&, unsigned short, Pet::TBuffer&) (Processor.cpp:22)
==27785==    by 0x578627: Pet::JobThread<Pet::PetProcessor>::run() (JobThread.h:66)
==27785==    by 0x4F81AB2: Poco::PooledThread::run() (in /data/home/app100619699/pet_srv/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.11)
==27785==    by 0x4F7D1D5: Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) (in /data/home/app100619699/pet_srv/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.11)
==27785==    by 0x54DE192: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.4.so)
==27785==    by 0x6161F0C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
```

The two string mentioned here have no relationship, and they are all local variables. Who can tell me why it happens or how can I find the real crash problem?

`Pet::BookConfiguration::~BookConfiguration()` is a compiler created destructor. It need not do anything because this class have no resource to release.

Comment: What happens in `~BookConfiguration()`?

Comment: Pet::BookConfiguration::~BookConfiguration() is a compiler created destructor. It need do noting because this class have no resource to release.

Comment: Can you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I can't, because the same code used in other place, but it clash only here.

Comment: @user1400047 it appears you've freed memory for a string that you attempt to copy later; see `Pet::PetProcessor::getUserBag`, in particular line 446 of *PetProcessor.cpp*

Comment: in the line 446, it's only dstruct the object of bagModel. I konw the memory problem is in the stl string object, but the two string have no relationship.

Answer (score 1):

From the error messages you're obviously using threads as well as some type of shared storage pool between threads.  You may be running into a problem where two different threads are attempting to destroy a shared resource when you shutdown the server, and whichever thread goes second creates the crash condition since destroying a shared object twice is undefined behavior.

Keep in mind the two separate threads need not actually use the same shared object, but if one thread destroys a pool that the other thread is using an object from, then the second thread can't destroy that object in the pool since the first thread already destroyed that resource.  So you could have either a sequencing issue, an ownership issue between thread resources, or a combination of both.